# MATLAB: Set and enforce axis properties immediately

Tags: matlab, plot

I have visualization code along the following lines:

```
scatter3(N(:,1), N(:,2), N(:,3), '.');
drawnow;
hold on;

for r = 1 : NUM
    % ... heavy calculations here
    trisurf(Tri(FBtri), XYZ(:,1), XYZ(:,2), XYZ(:,3));
    drawnow;
    hold on;
end

set(gca, 'ZDir', 'reverse');
```

I need to reverse the Z axis, and have found that it only works if I add the property setter after the entire code block for each subplot. This results in the entire subplot being rendered, and then visibly being reversed.

Is there a way that this property can be set and enforced before any contained future objects are computed/rendered, so that everything is shown reversed along the specified axis in the first place?

I would also welcome suggestions towards improving my usage of `hold` and `drawnow`, and on how to set and enforce axis reversal (or any axis property in general) for all subplots in the beginning itself with a single call to `set`, if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating some sample data, it seems the call to `scatter3` is the one reversing the axis back to original (in case the 'ZDir' was set previously).

What I often do when I create complex graphic figure and I don't want the high level plotting functions to mess up my layout:

1) Create the graphic object empty (with low level functions if you can)
2) Set all your axes properties
3) update the `XData`, `YData` (and `ZData`if relevant) of your graphic objects, using `set` (the call to `set` does not modify anything else on the figure/axe properties.

In your case, with the sample data i had to create, it seems that this works ok:

```
h.ax  = axes( 'ZDir', 'reverse' , 'NextPlot','add') ; 
h.hs3 = scatter3([],[],[],'.','Parent',h.ax) ;
set( h.hs3 , 'XData',N(:,1) , 'YData',N(:,2) , 'ZData',N(:,3) ) ;

for r = 1 : NUM
    % ... heavy calculations here
    h.t(r) = trisurf(Tri(FBtri), XYZ(:,1), XYZ(:,2), XYZ(:,3)) ;
end
```

The `'Nextplot','add'` property in the axes definition is the equivalent to `hold on`, so you do not need to call it after each plotting instruction

Note that in your case you do not seem to use the full functionality of `scatter3` (you do not specify a size for each point), so you could speed up things and simplify fairly the graphic execution by simply using a `line` object:

```
h.hs3 = line('XData',N(:,1) , 'YData',N(:,2) , 'ZData',N(:,3) , 'Parent',h.ax,'Marker','.','Linestyle','none') ;
```

This could replace the line 2 and 3 of the code I gave above.
The `line` object is just a series of data points in 3D (which contrary to the name, you do not have to necessarily link by an actual line), while the `scatter3` function create a `patch` object for each data point (much more graphic intensive, a waste of resources if you do not use them).

Calling `line` is also an example of *low level* function I was mentioning above. When you call `plot`, it's only a wrapper which create a `line` object and also does other things behind the scene. Creating the `line` object gives you more control, although sometimes it forces you to call them with more initial properties. For example the low level object behind the `scatter3` is a `specgraph.scattergroup`, which can be a bit more tricky to set up initially, so find your level of comfort.

As for the multiple calls to `drawnow`, unless you are doing a lot of things on the side and you need to regularly flush the event queue, I think most of them are unnecessary (many graphic calls will also update the figure by themselves). Try without them first, and if you really need a graphic update at some stage in your code, then you can use them (you probably also need a pause in your program, otherwise you may not have time to see the difference).